# -[UIImagePickerController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, ios8.1

I used UIImagePickerController to captrue photo from Camera. It used to work, but with iOS8 i am facing crash. Below is the code and crash log.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker {

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Logs:
Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

-[UIImagePickerController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Steps to reproduce the issue is, 
1. Click on Camera button in App. 
2. Camera opened. 
3. Click on Cancel on Camera UI. 
4. Click on Camera button again and the App is crashing now.

Comment: are you deallocating the ImagePicker anywhere?

Comment: Do you have ARC in the project?

Comment: Are you on Simulator ? Because you cannot use UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera on Simulator.

Comment: @Tendulkar: I am using ARC, not deallocation anywhere.

Comment: @TheRonin: I am testing in device only.

Comment: When are you getting the crash i.e while presenting or dismissing?

Comment: looks like the problem is not in the code you've posted. check viewWill/DidDisappear methods

Answer (score 0):

you should use
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

and [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I resolved it by passing "`NO`" in animation parameter in both these methods:

```
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```